# Change value of variable after context ends

Tags: python, python-3.x, contextmanager

In Python, how can I change a value after a context is ended?

```py
with my_context() as value:
    print(value)
print(value)
```

I would like value to be (for example) `1` inside of the context, but `2` after the context is ended.

I tried these but of course it doesn't work:

```py
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def number_function():
    number = 1
    yield number
    number = 2

class number_class:
    def __enter__(self):
        return 1
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        return 2

with number_function() as number:
    print(number)
print(number)
with number_class() as number:
    print(number)
print(number)
```

So what's a way to let the context manager be able to return a value to the calling code after the context is closed?

Is there a less verbose way than using an object like this:

```py
class my_context:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.number = 1
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.number = 2

with my_context() as context:
    print(context.number)
print(context.number)
```

Comment: The whole point of `with` is to syntactically contain the lifetime of `value`. I don't think there is a way to do that in a different way than to "survive" internal state as your last example does — nor should you strive for that.

Comment: This is not possible without doing something EXTREMELY hacky that you should not do.

Comment: Maybe a [coroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101084/coroutines-in-python-best-practices) is closer to what you're looking for? (another ref: https://stackabuse.com/coroutines-in-python/ )